# Access Violation Exception only appearing when running C# app without debugger attached

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, access-violation, gdcm

I have an application that works fine in Visual Studios 2008, and I am trying to get it into VS 2010 in order to use .NET 4, and I have a really weird problem.  When I run the code from either Release mode or Debug mode with the debugger attached (F5), I have no problems running the program.  However, when I run the program from either Release or Debug without the debugger attached (Shift+F5), I get an Access Violation Exception when I attempt to run some code in a dll from [GDCM](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gdcm/index.php?title=Main_Page).  I've created the dlls by using CMake and Swig and following the instructions [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gdcm/index.php?title=Configuring_and_Building_With_VS_.NET_2008_%28Include_C_sharp_wrapping%29) adjusting the instructions where necessary to build for VS 2010 and .NET 4.

Does any one have any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Here's an example of a program where the error occurs.  Again, if you create a project with the following as the program in VS 2010 it will run fine when the debugger is attached and fail if the debugger is not attached.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using gdcm;

namespace GDCMVS2010Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This program prints the patient name of a dicom file with gdcm");
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: [input.dcm]");
                return;
            }

            gdcm.Reader reader = new gdcm.Reader();
            reader.SetFileName(args[0]);
            reader.Read();

            gdcm.File file = reader.GetFile();

            gdcm.StringFilter filter = new gdcm.StringFilter();
            filter.SetFile(file);
            string value = filter.ToString(new gdcm.Tag(0x0010, 0x0010));

            Console.WriteLine("Patient Name: " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post repro code? The first things to check would be passing invalid data and p/Invoke signatures.

Comment: It appears every time I access any method from the dll.  I've posted some very simple example code.

Comment: I don't know how to post code that will allow the reproduction because it would require the whole VS solution with the appropriate gdcm dlls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because the version of SWIG I was using wasn't working correctly.  A new version of SWIG was recently released (version 2.0) which solves this problem.  After I reran CMake on GDCM, and then rebuilt GDCM with VS 2010, and put the GDCM dlls back into my example code, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should really start using GDCM specific groups to communicate your issues, see:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gdcm/index.php?title=General_questions#Where_are_the_GDCM_mailing_lists_.3F

100 of GDCM users are on this list and will be able to help you.

You should also provide a dataset (the DICOM file) to help with reproducing the bug.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The client profile misses out chunks of the .Net framework that you are **unlikely** to need on a client machine.  ASP .Net for example.  See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check your project properties.  I have encountered this problem when I had my Target Framework set to .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile, when it should have been the one w/out Client Profile.  Or vice versa.

Comment: I have multiple projects, and each one was set to the .NET 4 Framework.  I tried setting them all to the .NET 4 Client Profile, and the issue still appears.  What's the difference between the two frameworks?

Comment: alas, I cannot answer that question - it is something I have been meaning to explore further.  But I have encountered similar behavior and been like "WTF???".  And as a result of setting them all to one or the other profile, got everything to work w/out the access violation exception.  lol - a classic case of programming by accident.